# How to center a vertical image using the 'aside' tag?

Tags: html, css, image, center

For a school assignment I need to have an 'aside' tag in my HTML list. I choose an image for this, but now the image is above the rest of the website. I would like it to be centered. My hole website is centered, so I have on both sides a white vertical space where i would like to place a vertical image using 'aside'. I just started learning HTML and CSS so I am not very good in this. This is what I have so far:
HTML:

```
<aside> 
<img id="aside" src="images/aside4.jpg" alt="aside"/> 
</aside>
```

CSS:

```
#aside {
vertical-align: text-top;}
```

this is what I see: [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/x24hp4.png[/IMG]

Sorry if it does not make sense, I don't really know how to place the codes here (I am also Dutch so sorry for my bad language).

Comment: can you recreate what you have in a [http://jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net)

Answer (score 1):

Centering to vertical? Then do:

```
#aside{
   display: inline-block;
   vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I have tried it, but i still see this: [IMG]http://i59.tinypic.com/x24hp4.png[/IMG] I really don't know why it isn't working yet. :p